# How can I add a two column unique id to the mongodb in a meteor app?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to create a two column unique index on the underlying mongodb in a meteor app and having trouble.  I can't find anything in the meteor docs.  I have tried from the chrome console.  I have tried from term and even tried to point mongod at the /db/ dir inside .meteor .  I have tried

`Collection.ensureIndex({first_id: 1, another_id: 1}, {unique: true});` variations.

I want to be able to prevent duplicate entries on a meteor app mongo collection.

Wondering if anyone has figured this out?

I answered my own question, what a noob.

I figured it out.

1. Start meteor server
2. Open 2nd terminal and type `meteor mongo`

Then create your index...for example I did these for records of thumbsup and thumbsdown type system.

```
db.thumbsup.ensureIndex({item_id: 1, user_id: 1}, {unique: true})
db.thumbsdown.ensureIndex({item_id: 1, user_id: 1}, {unique: true})
```

Now, just gotta figure out a bootstrap install setup that creates these when pushed to prod instead of manually.

Comment: I posted my answer before I saw your edit, but note that by only enabling indexing on the server-side your users will think they're giving multiple upvotes even if those aren't actually being saved.  So probably best to also query before inserting as a workaround for that.

Comment: Would be better if you post your own answer separately from the question. Is more legible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#collections) "Minimongo currently doesn't have indexes. This will come soon."  And looking at the methods available on a Collection, there's no `ensureIndex`.

You can run `meteor mongo` for a mongo shell and enable the indexes server-side, but the Collection object still won't know about them.  So the app will let you add multiple instances to the Collection cache, while on the server-side the additional inserts will fail silently (errors get written to the output).  When you do a hard page refresh, the app will re-sync with server

So your best bet for now is probably to do something like:

```
var count = MyCollection.find({first_id: 'foo', another_id: 'bar'}).count()
if (count === 0)
    MyCollection.insert({first_id: 'foo', another_id: 'bar'});
```

Which is obviously not ideal, but works ok.  You could also enable indexing in mongodb on the server, so even in the case of a race condition you won't actually get duplicate records.

Comment: Thank you @danny I was just noticing that behavior as this post came in.

Comment: BTW, for anyone wondering, I implemented both.  The above logic on the front end and a unique index on the back end for safety and sanity sake.

Comment: this workaround still doesn't seem ideal.. what if you call `MyCollection.find` before the app has pulled all the data from the server?

Comment: Another pattern is to do inserts with a Meteor Method.  Something like: Meteor.call('addAFoo', fooData, function() {});

Answer (score 31):

## Collection._ensureIndex(index, options)

Searching inside Meteor source code, I found a bind to *ensureIndex* called `_ensureIndex`.
For single-key basic indexes you can follow the example of `packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js` that forces unique usernames on Meteor:

```
Meteor.users._ensureIndex('username', {unique: 1, sparse: 1});
```

For multi-key "compound" indexes:

```
Collection._ensureIndex({first_id:1, another_id:1}, {unique: 1});
```

The previous code, when placed **on the server side**, ensures that indexes are set.

## Warning

Notice _ensureIndex implementation warning:

> We'll actually design an index API later. For now, we just pass
>   through to Mongo's, but make it synchronous.

Comment: Any idea on what `space: 1` means there?

Comment: You mean `sparse`? It is when not all entries in given collection has this field set. So the index is "sparse". In this case not all Meteor.users need to have username set

Answer (score 3):

The Smartpackage [aldeed:collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) supports unique indices, as well as schema-validation. Validation will both occure on server and client (reactivly), so you can react on errors on the client.

Comment: But you can't use it to create compound indexes: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#index-and-unique

Answer (score 1):

Actually why not use upsert on the server with a Meteor.method and you could also send also track it with a ts:
// Server Only

```
Meteor.methods({
 add_only_once = function(id1,id2){
   SomeCollection.update(
     {first_id:id1,another_id:id2},{$set:{ts:Date.now()}},{upsert:True});
 }
});
```

// Client

```
Meteor.call('add_only_once',doc1._id, doc2._id);
```

// actual code running on server

```
if(Meteor.is_server) {
    Meteor.methods({
        register_code: function (key,monitor) {
             Codes.update({key:key},{$set:{ts:Date.now()}},{upsert:true});
        }
     ...
```

Comment: According to docs.meteor.com upsert is not supported yet with Mongo/MiniMongo stuff.  Otherwise that would be good.

Comment: upsert working?  very good news that code works now maybe latest releases of Meteor fixed this?  I would not know, haven't used Meteor in a couple of weeks.

Comment: I had no idea the `upsert` option was implemented on the server `Collection.update` call.. this finally gives me a cast-iron way to add a User to the Mongo table ONLY if it doesn't exist..

Comment: First, upserts aren't supported as of 12 Aug 2013. Second, you could put anything into that 3rd set of curly brace, it just gets ignored (just tested it on 064)

Comment: upserts are available since 0.6.6