# Can I create an index in a mongo collection with Meteor?

Tags: meteor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add a two column unique id to the mongodb in a meteor app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167604/how-can-i-add-a-two-column-unique-id-to-the-mongodb-in-a-meteor-app)

Is mongo indexing implemented in any way in Meteor yet?  I'm trying to index on unique names of documents in a collection.

Something like:

```
Collection.ensureIndex({name:1});
```

Comment: indexing isn't implemented in Minimongo, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167604/how-can-i-add-a-two-column-unique-id-to-the-mongodb-in-a-meteor-app/  Obviously you can always index mongo on your server directly.

Comment: Ahh thanks, voted to close my question.