# Multi fields unique index leading duplicate error in mongodb and meteor.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, nosql

I am using mongodb with meteor.js
To make multiple fields simultaneously from a collection be unique I use the following code

```
Messages._ensureIndex({ "numbers": 1, "messageListId": 1, "userId": 1},{unique: true , sparse: true});
```

messageListId and userId can be null (optional). 
When numbers field already exist and I want to insert a new object Mongo gives the following error

```
Error: MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: meteor.messages.$numbers_1_messageListId_1_userId_1  dup key: { : "09355270761", : null, : null } [409]
```

for instance I want to insert objects same below

```
Messages.insert({numbers:123,messageListId:456,userId:1});

Messages.insert({numbers:123});
```

I give the above mentioned error. How to do this in meteor.js?

I see these links but my issue is not resolved with their answer (updated)
:

[How can I add a two column unique id to the mongodb in a meteor app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167604/how-can-i-add-a-two-column-unique-id-to-the-mongodb-in-a-meteor-app])

[Creating Multifield Indexes in Mongoose / MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573753/creating-multifield-indexes-in-mongoose-mongodb])

[Error while setting up compound index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549742/error-while-setting-up-compound-index)

[sparse indexes and null values in mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608567/sparse-indexes-and-null-values-in-mongo)

Thanks for your attention.